# Python-opencv: 'ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp' on russian key press

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a Python script used to display images using opencv-python.
Control of the script is done using key-presses through `cv2.waitKey()`
The problem is, if I press a key while Russian keyboard layout is selected opencv crashes with:

```
ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 501
```

I cannot catch this error using python `try/except`.

How can I mitigate this problem?

Comment: First of all, report like this is rather useless if you don't specify which exact version of OpenCV this occurs with, what platform, which GUI backend (`qasciikey` seems to come from Qt, so it's the Qt backend). Create a [mcve] and provide detailed instructions on how to reproduce it (what exact keyboard layout will do this, which keys do it, which don't). The assert seems to come from `char QTest::keyToAscii(Qt::Key key)`. From some digging, the `QTEST_ASSERT` there will trigger even in non-debug builds, and on *nix with Qt's default message handler the resulting fatal error cause coredump.

Comment: The opencv function that calls it ([`void CvWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *evnt)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#L2158)) begins with a comment "Need more test here !". Apparently this was one of the combinations that wasn't tested (with this assert, the else branch will never get taken). Submit a bug report on the [OpenCV issue tracker](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues). If you're fluent in C++ and Qt, you can try to patch it (and submit the patch), otherwise you'll need to wait for someone else to volunteer to do it.

Comment: Until then, either don't use Russian layout, or perhaps try to build OpenCV to use the GTK backend and see if that behaves better. If all you use highgui for is to wait for keypress, consider a different method of doing so. If you do some visualization, consider implementing your own UI (HighGUI is really more of a convenience for quick prototyping).